# Migrations in Entity Framework Core 2.0 - How to specify environment or pass arguments

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm playing with EF Core 2.0 and have 3 env in my app: dev, staging and prod. Now I want to apply db schema to specific database. However I faced with a problem. When I executing `dotnet ef database drop (update)` for example, it's trying to get production env by default.

How could I specify what environment should be used? My DbContextFactory looks like that:

```
public class MyDbContextFactory : IDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>
    {
        public MyDbContext Create(string[] args) => //how to pass something to this args?
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build().Services.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>();
    }
```

it was something like: 
`dotnet ef database drop -e development` in version `1.1`, but this was removed from version `2.0`.

`set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=development
 dotnet ef database drop`

also seems not working.

Answer (score 4):

What I gathered from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet) is that the `-e MyCustomEnvironment` is not available in the EF Core Design Tools for Core 2.x

To set Environment Variables I discovered you have the following choices depending on your usecase

#### Environment Variable for this CMD Session (Windows):

`set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT <Environment Name>`

#### Environment Variable in your User Environment (Windows):

`setx ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT <Environment Name>`

#### Also possible via GUI (Windows)

"Start" -> "Edit the system environment Variables" -> "Environment Variables" -> "New"

#### Environment Variable for this Shell session (Linux):

`export ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=<Environment Name>`

#### Environment Variable in you User Environment (Linux):

`cd ~
echo 'export ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=<Environment Name>' >> .bashrc`

This will actually export the Variable everytime .bashrc is executed. I'm not sure if this is the way to go on Linux but it worked for me.

Also in my case I didn't want the StartUp code to run since I feel like for a DesignTime action its not neccessary to register all the Services etc of my Application. This could be done like so:

```
        var basePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

        var envName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");

        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(basePath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{envName}.json", true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        var config = builder.Build();

        var customOptions = config.GetSection("database").Get<DatabaseOptions>();
```

Also if you have more complex szenarios you now might want to create some small batch or shell skripts

Comment: Setting environment variable doesn't work.  Still targeting dev instance in spite of ASPNETCORE_Environment set to Production

Comment: Well by default EF ignores your Environment Variables. You have to read it out yourself and apply the settings in your DbContextDesignTimeFactory. So this could be why its not working but w/o info on how your setup is I cant really help you

Comment: "by default...", not according to Brice, https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/pull/8307 and as you indicated at the very top of this proposed answer

Comment: Finally got it working by a combo of following this guide, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/, and creating a new project and importing in the deltas between what I had in my code for 1.1.  It then recognized the env var and published to my production environment

Comment: with the "by default" I meant it will notice the variable and it will be set in your Startup.cs IHostingEnvironment but it wont be there in your IDbDesignTimeContextFactory and your migrations will still use the default connection. So you have to reaf the EnvVar in your IDbDesignTimeContextFactory like shown in my last code segment.

Answer (score 1):

Well, to be honest I don't know exact answer for that question. I think environment variables should work, but the way how you set them are pretty much depend from environment you working for. So it will be one story on linux, different for on Windows (again different for PowerShell) and something elso on MacOS.

this works for me on `Linux` and in bash console on `Windows`:

```
ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT="{NAME_OF_ENV}";dotnet ef {somecommand you want to execute}
```

In `Powershell` you could try something like that:

```
$env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT="{NAME_OF_ENV}"
dotnet ef {somecommand you want to execute}
```

However, even it's migration, it's still a console app inside. So you could just ask user to enter environment from console with something like:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter environment you want to use");
var env = Console.ReadLine();
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
       .UseEnvironment(env)
       .UseStartup<Startup>()
       .Build().Services.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>();
```

This is of course not a perfect solution, but if you out of options - this could be a workaround. You could pass other param that way as well.

Comment: Setting environment variable doesn't work.  Still targeting dev instance in spite of ASPNETCORE_Environment set to Production